# Add URL through Angular Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to add URL for title? URL should be accessible on HTML page, Can anyone please specify in my case how should i use $sce.trustAsHtml

```
        var trustedHtml = [];
        var calEvents = [];
        var eventSources = [];

        for (var int = 0; int < json1.length; int++) {

            $scope.html = '<a href="#">' + json1[int].comment + '</a>';

            $scope.eventSources = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
            console.log(eventSources);
            alert(eventSources);
            var d = new Date(json1[int].reminderDate);

            calEvents.push(
            {
                title: json1[int].comment,// I want to add url to title
                start: d,
                allDay: true
            }
             //console.log(calEvents)
        );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-bind-html`

```
<h1 data-ng-bind-html="eventSources"></h1>
```

Comment: At View side i have used   <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" calendar="myCalendar1" class="calendar" ng-bind-html="eventSources" data-ng-model="eventSources" ng-if="eventSources.length > 0"></div>

Comment: @Duckkiee I dont get your requirement, sorry for not understanding

Comment: On html page i'm unable to click on link. On html page i found all title <a href="#">'myTitle '</a>';. Is there any way to add url to my title

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Remove `int` from `var` set `var i`

Comment: It works for me :     url: 'javascript:angular.element(document.getElementById("eventSources")).scope().TestAngularMethod();